# C# measure process CPU usage on multiple processors windows server

Tags: c#

I tried to monitor a windows service CPU usage on a windows server with 24 processors. I used

```
    _cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
                        "Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, true);
    _cpuCounter.NextValue()/100 //most time, it is more than 100%, which is not correct.
```

But it does not give me the correct Process CPU usage.

Comment: How do you know that its not correct?

Comment: If the result of more than 100% processor time usage disturbs you, just divide it on Environment.ProcessorCount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are not incorrect. It's just that `NextValue()` will return values greater than 100 when your process uses more than one CPU and the individual values add up to "more" than 100%.

For instance, if your process uses 50% of CPU0 and 60% of CPU1 the result will be 110% usage of all *potentially available* CPU cycles across all CPUs/cores (which is expressed as 200% for dual core processors).

If you want a value taking the number of processors into acount (i.e. mapping `110` to `55` on a dual core machine) try dividing the retrieved value by the number of processors instead:

```
_cpuCounter.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount
```